# ComboBox и индексирование

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server

Не могу понять как сделать чтобы все корректно добавлялась в БД

```cs
private void tbSave_Click_Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (f == 0)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand insertData = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [Album]" +
                $" VALUES (@name_album,@date_zap,@date_sale,@group_id,@country_id,@studio_id,@distrub_id)", sqlConnection);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_album", tbName.Text);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_zap", dtZap.SelectedDate);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_sale", dtSale.SelectedDate);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group_id",cmbGroup.SelectedIndex);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_id", cmbCountry.SelectedIndex);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studio_id", cmbStudio.SelectedIndex);
            insertData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@distrub_id", cmbDistrub.SelectedIndex);
            insertData.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Успешно");
            WindowAlbum();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbGroup"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="220,83,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="179"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
          Height="24"
          Grid.Row="1"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=cmbGroup}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cmbGroups}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Group"
          SelectedValuePath="id" />
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Album(
    id_album INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    name_album nvarchar(500),
    date_zap DATE,
    date_sale DATE,
    group_id INT REFERENCES Group_(id_Group) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    country_id INT REFERENCES Country(id_Country) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    studio_id INT REFERENCES Studio(id_Studio) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    distrub_id INT REFERENCES Distrub(id_Distrub) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

При добавлении некорректно добавляется к примеру cmbGroup:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении к примеру из `ComboBox` выбираем **й1й** соответственно в БД добавляется **311к** так как перечислении в сomboBox начинается с 0 мы выбираем 3 список получается 2 и `id_Grooup = 2` а хотелось бы чтобы работала корректно когда выбираем **й1й** в БД добавлялось **й1й**

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом.

Comment: Используйте SelectedValue а не индекс

Comment: @aepot все добавил

Comment: Да не вопрос всегда пожалуйста